# What does 'to treat with a thing desired' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entreat

> To treat with, or in respect to, a thing desired; hence, to ask for earnestly.

From the example ('some late visitor entreating entrance at my chamber door') I understand that 'entreat' can mean roughly 'to ask for earnestly', but I don't understand understand the first part of the meaning.

Am I correct that they mean either 'to treat with a thing desired' or 'to treat in respect to a thing desired'?

I glanced over the senses of 'treat' and I didn't find anything matching this context.

What do these phrases mean, and what does 'treat' mean in them?

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of using Wiktionary, but I think in this case they are a little off on that first definition. It seems to me that it tries to mash two meanings into one line, exactly as you say:

> **1.1**. To treat with a thing desired
> **1.2**. To treat in respect to a thing desired

The second meaning is clear enough. ["Treat"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/treat#Verb) here is used as in definitions 1, 2, and 4: to *negotiate, discourse, or beseech [of someone]* in respect to a thing desired.

The first meaning is confusing to me because it seems to be redundant—it is better defined one line down the page:

> **2.** To beseech or supplicate (a person); to prevail upon by prayer or solicitation; to try to persuade.

If you look up "entreat" in other dictionaries you will see that they generally split the two meanings into two separate definitions.

Comment: But what does 'treat' mean with 'with'? That's what I don't understand; I see e.g. at your link there is the first meaning (bargain), but there 'with' is used with a person, not with a 'thing' (desired)... it also can mean chemical action (9th at your link), but it's not that... there's also 'treat with love/care', but it doesn't fit in here to me either ('thing desired' is not a mental state)...

Comment: @ledonter the way I read this definition it is using "thing desired" as similar to "person," which is why I think it is redundant.